# Viewing inlined files in IE

Tags: html, internet-explorer

I am writing an HTML5 page which needs to have all of it's support scripts/styles/images/data inlined into the html.  (I know it's not good web design, but that's the way it needs to be.)

All the media I inline are base64-encoded strings with their mime-types. For the images I display, making an image with a src containing the mime-type and string seems to be fine.

For non-image/text media however, is there a way to access that data from the html? I've tried making a link with an href containing the string, but for long files the string get truncated in FF/Chrome, and does not work at all in IE 7/8/9.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

> For non-image/text media however, is there a way to access that data from the html?

Sadly, not really, no. IE [has heavy limitations on `data:` URLs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc848897%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). They are not supported at all in IE7, and even in IE8 and 9 there are size and other limits. (See the linked MSDN page.)